# Run nested http-requests with forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have data like:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    pets: [
      {
        id: 11,
        pet: 'Zebra'
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        pet: 'Giraffe'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

which I get from a get request. For each item in and array and therein `pets` array, I need to fetch the `mood` for each `pet` from another endpoint based on the id, which returns for example:

```
{
  id: 11,
  mood: 'hungry'
}
```

So final result would look like this after requests:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "pets": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "pet": "Zebra",
        "mood": "hungry"
     },
     {
       "id": 12,
       "pet": "Giraffe",
       "mood": "happy"
     }
   ]
  }
]
```

I've made an attempt using `forkJoin` for all the `pets`, but cannot get it to work correctly. In below Stackblitz is one attempt:

```
getCombined() {
  return of(this.parent).pipe(
    switchMap(families => {
      return families.map(family => {
        return forkJoin(
          family.pets.map(pet => {
            return this.getMood(pet.id).pipe(
              map(data => {
                pet.mood = data.mood;
                return family;
              })
            )
          })
        )
      })
    }), switchMap((d) => d)
  );
}
```

It correctly returns 3 outer objects, but they are all the same object it seems. How to get the correct result? Thanks in advance, and here is the Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttpcvu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it out like this:

```
  getCombined() {
    return forkJoin( // don't need the of and whatnot.
      this.parent.map(family => {
        return forkJoin(
          family.pets.map(pet => {
            return this.getMood(pet.id).pipe(
              map(mood => {
                pet.mood = mood.mood; //assign mood
                return pet; // return populated pet.
              })
            );
          })
        ).pipe(
          map(pets => {
            family.pets = pets; // assign the pets here
            return family; // return populated family.
          })
        )
      })
    );
  }
```

blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwqclm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

you need to have a forkjoin for the outer set and the inner set for this to execute correctly, and you need to do your assignments in the correct places.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. Still new to more "complicated" rxjs things, but I'll get there ;)  Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

here in the below code, we are streaming the array of objects as observable streams, then
again streaming pets and creates the fake Obserbale(api call) and map the response with pet properties, then again making all the pets with their respective Owner.

```js
const { fromEvent, merge, of, from } = rxjs;
const { map, filter, concatMap, toArray, tap, delay, concatAll, mergeMap,mergeAll } = rxjs.operators;
// Write TypeScript code!
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>if you dont want Asynchronous request then you can use concat instead of merge</h1>`;
console.clear();

const data$ = of([{
  id: 1, pets: [
    { id: 11, pet: 'Zebra' },
    { id: 12, pet: 'Giraffe' }
  ]
},
{
  id: 2, pets: [
    { id: 21, pet: 'Zebra' },
    { id: 22, pet: 'Giraffe' }
  ]
}
])
const q = (x) => {
  // Fake http call 
  // you can make your api call here 
  const oneSecondSource$ = of(x['id']).pipe(delay(1 * x.id))
  return oneSecondSource$.pipe(map(abs => {
    const res = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1)) === 0 ? 'hungry' : 'happy';
    // and map the resulatant mood
    return { ...x, mood: res }
  }));
}

const p = (obj) => {
  // mapping each
  return from(obj.pets).pipe(mergeMap(q), toArray(), map(a => {
    return { id: obj.id, pets: a }
  }))
}
const example$ = data$.pipe(mergeMap(a => from(a).pipe(map(p))),
  mergeAll(),
  toArray()
);
example$.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Here is the [stackblitz  solution you can refer](https://rxjs-nested-request-of-observable.stackblitz.io)